# Get which keys are pressed in the moment

Tags: javascript, keyevent

I am writing a little plugin for Javascript, in the moment, I need to hide a element on other element blur. But, the element should not be hidden, if the shift or ctrl are pressed.

So...

I need to find which keys are pressed in any given time in the code.

At any given type, i mean, outside a keypress event. In my code i need to find if the ctrl key or the shift key are pressed during a blur event.

The blur event is not associated with a key, on keydown it's possible to do this:

```
e.ctrlKey
```

This is the part of the code that will need the answer.

```
$('.bk-select-base').on('blur', (e)=>{
    if(e.ctrlKey){ return; } // e is not a key event
    if( navigator.isCtrlKey ){ return; } // something like this
    setTimeout(()=>{
        // It's 10PM, it's ugly. Just ignore this part
        $($(e)[0].currentTarget).parent().find('.bk-select-list').addClass('hidden');
    }, 100 );            
});
```

So. I expect to find a place where i can request which keys are pressed in this exact moment. Without the need of a key event.

Comment: You can use the `keydown` or `keypress` events for that, the `blur` event is for when focus leaves the input, not keys.

Comment: You will need a seperate event to track the key.

Comment: With jQuery you can "bundle" the events into one handler and delegate the events within the callback.